# Including a gif in html page

Tags: html, gif

I have no idea why a simple gif image is not being loaded properly. In the html code I have the usual

```
  <img src="/img/loading.gif" alt="Loading" title="Loading" />
```

and the file is in that folder. The weird thing is that if I place there `/img/logo.png` the image is loaded properly.

The filename is correct, I've even copied and pasted it renaming the original files.

PS tested on Firefox 12, Safari 6.0.2 Chrome 23.0.1271.95 (all for Mac)

Comment: Given that the file exists, it _should_ work. The code is fine. Is it possible that `loading.gif` is not being served properly by the web server?

Comment: Check if you uploaded the file on your server. It should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was probably a corrupt gif. Your code should work with some other gif. If you really want to get the corrupt gif to work, try opening it in an image editor program and then resave it as gif (or any other format).

Comment: Yes, that was the problem, I had come to the same conclusion (see answer below)

Answer (score 0):

Silly question, but what does your gif look like?  Is it transparent, or white against a white background?

One possible way to diagnose the problem would be (in Chrome or Firefox), to press F12 to bring up the developer tools and look at your img element to see if the image has loaded in the DOM.

Comment: Well the image is the usual rotating circle, black lines rotating on a transparent bg. Safari and Chrome show the broken image symbol, while Firefox the alt text.

Comment: Do you have an online example, or can you put together a jsfiddle to demostrate the problem?

Comment: Unfortunately it's all local, I was trying to create a jsfiddle but then realized what might have been the problem, I've posted the answer, thank's!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem was with the gif file, probably somehow broken. I got it from a random resources web site and downloaded from it.

I've tried with a new file got from `http://www.ajaxload.info/` now with the code unchanged it works fine.

Edit: the "broken" gif file was working fine elsewhere in the system (e.g. quicklook).